# Apache dav_svn - svn co yields 'moved permanently'

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I have a couple of subversion repositories which are working fine. I can check out via protocols `svn` and `svn+ssh`.

In order to check out the repositories behind a restrictive firewall I wanted to enable `http(s)` access via Apache mod_dav_svn.

The repositories are accesible via browser but as soon as I try to check out a repository I get an `svn: Repository moved to 'url'`.
If I try to check out like this:

```
svn co https://servername/repo
```

it tells me that it moved to `https://servername/repo/` (note the trailing slash) and if I try to check out that exact url I get the `moved permanently` again but the url is the same as the one I entered.

This is the apache config in use for the repositories:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName servername
ServerAlias servername

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/key

DocumentRoot /svn

<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

DAV svn
SVNParentPath /svn
SVNListParentPath on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "SVN"
AuthUserFile /svn/users
#AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/acl
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Does anyone have any hints or pushes in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

From [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic)

> Be sure that when you define your new Location, it doesn't overlap
>   with other exported locations. For example, if your main DocumentRoot
>   is exported to /www, do not export a Subversion repository in
>   `<Location /www/repos>`. If a request comes in for the URI
>   /www/repos/foo.c, Apache won't know whether to look for a file
>   repos/foo.c in the DocumentRoot, or whether to delegate mod_dav_svn to
>   return foo.c from the Subversion repository. The result is often an
>   error from the server of the form 301 Moved Permanently.

For this reason, I prefer **never** have SVN-location in the root of VHost and, for me, `DocumentRoot /svn` + `SVNParentPath /svn` seems as **big no-no**.

Just in paranoid-mode (can't refer directly on authoritative source) I always have

- SVN-location as node deeper root in web-tree
- SVNParentPath placed outside web-tree
- Trailing slash in Location and SVNParentPath| SVNPath parameter